# How is CSR usage in fabric-ca-client-config.yaml

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, ca

From [fabric-ca document](http://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html#csr-fields), when it generates `fabric-ca-client-config.yaml`, how to combine with csr field? Its default cn is admin, When I generate admin2 who has hf.Registrar.Roles user authority，could csr.cn value be admin2?

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little unclear to me, but I'll try.  Feel free to clarify the question is this is not what you are asking.

The "csr" section of fabric-ca-server-config.yaml controls what goes into the root or intermediate CA certificate as created by the fabric-ca-server, assuming the root or intermediate CA certificate does not already exist.  So the csr.cn value can be anything that you want.  It is just the common name given to the fabric-ca-server's signing identity.

This is not to be confused with anything under "registry.identities" nor with anything dynamically registered.  These are identities of entities that are issued certificates by fabric-ca-server, and in this case, the CN of the issued certificate will always be the enrollment ID of the identity.  But this is for issued certificates, while the "csr" section applies to CA signing certificates which are used to issue certificates.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I mainly point to fabric-ca-client command related to csr cn  in the  fabric-ca-client-config.yaml ?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [@Keith Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8209699/keith-smith), the question is a little unclear to me but I'll try.

> could csr.cn value be admin2?

If you want to define your own cn, you should define your fabric-ca-client-config.yaml file. It is generated by default if it doesn't exis previously.

On the other hand, as [@Keith Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8209699/keith-smith) said, this is not to be confused with anything under "registry.identities" nor with anything dynamically registered.